# Lagrange Multipliers Question - some extremum points are missed (not detected) by the method

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I was reading about Lagrange multipliers. My book says that if $f(x,y,z)$ has in the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ an extremum under the condition that $g(x,y,z) = k$, and if $\nabla g \ne (0,0,0)$, then there exists a number $\lambda$ such that

$$\nabla f (x_0, y_0, z_0) = \lambda \nabla g (x_0, y_0, z_0) \tag{1}$$
and
$$g(x_0, y_0, z_0) = k \tag{2}$$

But then I was working through this simple example.

Find the extremums of $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ under the condition
$g(x,y,z) = x+y+z = 1$ where $x,y,z \ge 0$

I noticed that here the Lagrange method (i.e. solving the system $(1), (2)$) misses to detect/find the  extremum points $P (x,y,z)$, such that e.g. $x = 0$ and $y+z = 1$ and $y,z$ are positive.

It only detects/finds the four points $(1/3, 1/3, 1/3), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$.

So what am I missing here?

I guess in my book the theorem is stated somewhat informally, and that's why the Lagrange method is missing to detect these points.

So why are these points $P$ missed? I mean, they are obviously extremum (minimum) points of $f$ but they do not satisfy the system $(1), (2)$ for any $\lambda$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method of Lagrange multipliers works when we are after the locally extreme points of a class $C^1$ function $f$ on a region of the type $g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=k$, for a class $C^1$ function $g$. That's not the case here, since your region is a strict subset of $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid g(x,y,z)=1\}$ rather then the whole set. So, there can be (and, in this case, there are) locally extreme points at the boundary of your region.

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure I get it quite well. E.g. could it be that in some cases the Lagrange method misses e.g. all minimum points because they are all on the boundary? In my case it did catch three minimum points even though they were also on the boundary. Where can I find a good formal statement of this Lagrange method theorem?

Comment: In other words, if I solve the system of (1) and (2), what can I claim? That I have found the min and max of $f$ but maybe not found all its minimum/maximum points? Can I claim that?

Comment: Or... could be that even though I have solved the system $(1),(2)$, I have still missed all min points OR all max points?

Comment: The Lagrange multipliers theorem is usually stated the way that I mentioned in my answer (that is, for sets of the form $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb R^n\mid g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=k\}$). And, yes, the method (when applied in situations such as yours) can miss all minimum points. Just take $f(x,y)=x$ and the region $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\wedge x\geqslant0\}$. Then the points at which the minimum is located are the points $(0,\pm1)$, which will not be detected.

Comment: Hm... that's a good simple example indeed. Very interesting. But if we abandon/drop the condition $x \ge 0$, then there's no problem, we will detect all min and all max points by using the Lagrange method, right? I mean this condition is the crux here, right?

Comment: Yes, without that extra condition, everything works.

Answer (score 3):

This is an additional remark to the correct reply from José:

it is possible (though not always feasible) to introduce new variables and in the process shift the problem to a higher dimensional one that has no boundary.

Indeed by introducing $x_0,y_0,z_0$ and add the conditions
$$
x=x_0^2\\
y=y_0^2\\
z=z_0^2\\
$$
We can define the Lagrangian by
$$
L=xyz+\lambda(x+y+z-1)+\mu_x(x-x_0^2)+\mu_y(y-y_0^2)+\mu_z(z-z_0^2)
$$
Now, if we look at the critical points $\nabla L=0$ in the 10-dimensional space we find all critical points, even those that were originally on the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

For instance. Using the Lagrangian depicted in the answer from @maxmilgram we can find the following stationary points

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
f& x & y & z & \lambda & \mu_x&\mu_y&\mu_z & x_0^2& y_0^2& z_0^2\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & y & 1-y & 0 & (y-1) y & 0 & 0 & 0 & y & 1-y \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & x & 0 & 1-x & 0 & 0 & (x-1) x & 0 & x & 0 & 1-x \\
 0 & x & 1-x & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (x-1) x & x & 1-x & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{27} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{9} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

where $f = x y z$. Note that in the third row we have conditions: $y \ge 0$ and $1-y\ge 0$ etc.