# Cobb-Douglas model - Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I came across this problem and I almost solved it... but not quite, I think.

It's about this model.

[Cobb-Douglas Production Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobb%E2%80%93Douglas_production_function)

OK, so let's say we have this function

$f(x,y) = K . x^\alpha . y^{1-\alpha}$

Here $K > 0, \alpha \in (0,1)$ are some constants.

We want to find the maximum of $f$ under the additional condition that

$g(x,y) = mx + ny = p$

Here $m,n,p > 0$ are also constants.

Also, we have that $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$
because $x$ is labor input and $y$ is capital input in the Cobb-Douglas model.

My book tells me to use the Lagrange multipliers method to find the maximum of $f$.

OK, so I applied the Lagrange multipliers method i.e. I created this system of three equations (for $x,y,\lambda$), and I solved it.

$f'_x(x,y) = \lambda g'_x (x,y)$
$f'_y(x,y) = \lambda g'_y (x,y)$
$g(x,y) = p$

So I was able to find that the function $f$ has **an extremum** at the point $(x_0, y_0) = (\alpha . p / m, (1-\alpha).p / n)$

But then I have some doubts.

1. How do I know that this extremum is a **maximum** and not a **minimum**? How do I justify that it's a maximum? Is it enough to compare $f(x_0, y_0)$ with say $f(0, p /n) = f(p/m, 0) = 0$ in order to conclude that we have a maximum at $(x_0, y_0)$ Somehow this doesn't sound very convincing to me.
2. It also bothers me that $f$ is defined only when $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$. So because of these additional restrictions on $x$ and $y$, is the Lagrange multipliers method applicable here at all? I guess it is because that's the method my book tells me to use but still... wanted to ask that here. These additional restrictions bother me because of what I learned yesterday in another question that I asked.

[Lagrange Multipliers Question - some extremum points are missed (not detected) by the method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753193/lagrange-multipliers-question-some-extremum-points-are-missed-not-detected-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method for solving a two-variable maximization problem with one equality constraint**

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuously differentiable functions and let $c$ be a number. If the problem

$$\text{$\max_{x,y}f(x,y)$ subject to $g(x,y)=c$ and $(x,y)\in S$}$$

has a solution, then it may be found as follows:

1. Find all the values of $(x,y,\lambda)$ for which

$$\begin{align*}&\text{(a) $(x,y)$ is an interior point of $S$}\\ &\text{(b) $(x,y,\lambda)$ satisfies the first-order conditions and the constraint:}\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}L_x(x,y)&=0\\ L_y(x,y)&=0 \\ g(x,y)&=c. \end{align*}$$

2. Find all the points $(x,y)$ in the interior of $S$ that satisfy

$$\begin{align*}g_x(x,y)&=0\\ g_y(x,y)&=0 \\ g(x,y)&=c. \end{align*}$$

3. If the set $S$ has any boundary points, find all the boundary points that solve the problem $\max_{x,y}f(x,y)$ subject to the two conditions $g(x,y) = c$ and $(x,y)$ is a boundary point of $S$.
4. The points $(x,y)$ you have found at which the value $f(x,y)$ is largest are the maximizers of the function $f$.

---

You have already carried out step 1. In many cases that will give your solution. However, you have to check points that do not satisfy the constraint qualification. A solution $(x^*,y^*)$ satisfies the constraint qualification if $g_x(x^*,y^*)\neq 0$ or $g_y(x^*,y^*)\neq 0$. Step 2 finds all the points in the constraint set that do not satisfy the constraint qualification, as they could potentially be solutions that are not found in step 1. Step 3 addresses your concern related to your previous question by also checking the boundary points of $S$.

---

In your case, steps 2 and 3 are as follows:

2. $g_x(x,y)=m\neq 0$ and $g_y(x,y)=n\neq 0$, so there are no points satisfying the conditions in step 2. (The constraint qualification is satisfied at all points.)
3. $S=\{(x,y)\ |\ x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}$, and the boundary points are where $x=0$ or $y=0$. When $x=0$ or $y=0$ we have $f(x,y)=0$. Since the point you found in step 1 gives $f(x,y)>0$, there is no need to go any further.

---

To address you first concern, once we have proved a maximum exist, then we know it must be found in step 1, 2, or 3. If a minimum exists, then we know it must satisfy the conditions in step 1, 2, or 3 with  $\max$ replaced by $\min$. It is step 4 that then allows you to distinguish between which candidates are minimizers or maximizers.

To prove existence of a maximum and minimum usually involves application of the extreme value theorem. In your case the constraint set is compact (it is the line $g(x,y)=p$ for $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$) and the objective function is continuous, so you know both a maximum and minimum exist.

In your case, the minimum is $0$, and this occurs at boundary points of $S$ satisfying the constraint, i.e. at the points $(0,p/n)$ and $(p/m,0)$.

Comment: Thank you. This procedure seems very detailed and clear.

Comment: The set $S$ captures the constraints other than the equality constraint. The constraint set for the maximization problem is the intersection of $S$ with the set defined by the equality constraint. In your case the constraint set is the intersection of $S=\{(x,y) \ | \ x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}$ and the line defined by $g(x,y)=p$. So the set $S$ does have interior points; any points where $x>0$ and $y>0$ are interior.

Comment: Yeah, got it, that's why I deleted my comment. But you can keep yours. Thank you. I will reread all this and think it over.

Comment: Is there any book you can recommend, where this and similar optimization problems are described so well as in your answer?

Comment: These online notes by the economist Martin Osborne are very useful (it is where I got the method): https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/int/i

The Sydsaeter and Hammond book Mathematics for Economic Analysis (referred to in Osborne's notes) is quite similar in level to his notes.

Comment: OK, thanks a log once again.

Comment: https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/men/t  See "Procedure for solving a two-variable maximization problem with an equality constraint"